# Linux залипает shift

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Linux Mint 17 Rebecca. Заметил что при переключении раскладки ctrl+shift залипает shift начинает печатать заглавными буквами, потвторное нажаите shift отключает такое поведение. Оболочка Mate.

Comment: Можно ведь переназначить комбинации клавиш для раскладки?

Comment: Если дома дверь сломается Вы ее чинить будете или через балкон ходить? =)

Comment: Ахахаха, если дома сломается дверь, то куплю новую. :)

Comment: проинспектируйте все настройки клавиатурных сочетаний. это можно сделать мышкой.

Comment: других сочетаний не настроено. Шифт залипает как-то виртуально, пробовал на разных клавиатурах.

Answer (score -1):

Клавиатура -> раскладки -> параметры раскладки клавиатуры -> переколючение на другую раскладку alt+shift если не установлено. Для cianomon приминимо для остальных столов аналогично. Если этот параметр не стоит то раскладка может работать на будут залипать alt или shift.